# matching 1 column with other 3 columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a column code and another discount as below:

```
Klient  |   discount
--------+-----------
123     |   10
232     |   5
322     |   7
451     |   2
```

On another table I have the levels of client code as below:

```
Tier 1  |   Tier2   |   Tier3
--------+-----------+--------
023     |   123     |   333
232     |   311     |   455
```

I need to have something like this (the klient field could be in any tier column, so have to check where it is...)

```
Klient  |   discount    |   tier
--------+---------------+---------
123     |   10          |   2
232     |   5           |   1
```

I have done it by running three append queries over the same table changing the relationship field (from klient to each tier, and deleting the nulls).

But was wondering if there is a more direct / efficient way...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I had a very similar problem before, I know solution for mysql not quite sure if it also workds for sql

Comment: @nafas: is it sql based? if so could you post it so I can try? thanks!

Comment: Sorry mate, I misunderstood the question. I am not quite sure how to get the tier 1, 2 and etc

Comment: what table is the discount held in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Tier1 AS Klient, 1 AS Tier
FROM t2
UNION ALL SELECT Tier2, 2
FROM t2
UNION ALL SELECT Tier3, 3
FROM t2
```

This will give you the following:

```
Klient  |   Tier
--------+-------
023     |   1   
232     |   1   
123     |   2
311     |   2
333     |   3
455     |   3
```

If you save this query as `q1`, you can then join on the first table:

```
SELECT Klient, Discount, Tier
FROM q1
INNER JOIN t1 ON q1.Kleint = t1.Klient
```

NB. Is there any particular reason your table has a separate column for each tier? Ideally, the structure of the table should be that of the union query, and the split-by-columns should be done with a cross-tab query.

Comment: I received the data like this.... they have it in 2 excel files, one for tier 1 and one for the other 2

Answer (score 0):

use this subquery to transform tiers:

```
(SELECT tier1 k, 1 t FROM tiers
UNION ALL
SELECT tier2 k, 2 t FROM tiers
UNION ALL
SELECT tier3 k, 3 t FROM tiers) my_tiers
```